# Is it possible to run chef-client from within a knife exec command?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Looking to update node attributes (derived from a cookbook) using `knife exec`. I'd like to trigger `chef-client` after that so the cookbook can make the corresponding updates on the node. Is it possible to trigger the check-in from the same `knife exec` block, or do I need a separate `knife ssh` call (or similar) in order to check the node in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`knife exec` executes Ruby code on the Chef Server. Indeed, you need to log into the nodes and trigger `chef-client`, either through `knife ssh`, Chef Push Jobs, Rundeck, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Stephen. Glad to get validation on what I assumed was the answer.

Comment: Exec does not run code on the server, it runs locally on the workstation.

Comment: Sorry, makes sense, of course. I was more thinking of the modification of the server-side objects (which are done on the workstation).